# Why is $\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{2}\right) = 1$ and not $5$?

Tags: trigonometry

I know that $\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 1.$  So wouldn't extracting the five and then multiplying it by $1$ give you five?  However, when I google and check the answer, $\sin(5\pi/2)$ has the same value as $\sin(\pi/2)$. Can anyone explain this?

[image: TRIG QUESTION]

Comment: It's a picture of the expression $\sin(\frac{5\pi}{2})$, what is there to explain?

Comment: Sin(x) is not linear. You are not allowed to "extract the 5"

Comment: How would I then know what 5pi/2 is. Since it is not on the unit circle?

Comment: Regarding why you get the same answer: sin(x) is periodic with period=2pi. Thus, sin(2.5 pi) =sin(2pi+pi/2)=sin(pi/2) =1

Comment: Yes, an angle of $\frac {5\pi}2$ is on the unit circle.  $2\pi$ takes you once around and you have $\frac \pi 2$ yet to go, so $\frac {5 \pi}2$ is straight up to $(0,1)$

Comment: Are you claiming that $\sin 5x = 5\sin x$ for arbitrary $x$? That's not true at all.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: $\sin(\frac{5\pi}{2})$ does not mean $\sin$ times $\frac{5\pi}{2}$.  Confusing to beginners!

Comment: Because getting five units away from a diameter on a unit circle is hard, maybe?

Answer (score 6):

The $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions are periodic with period $2\pi$;

that is, $\sin(\theta+2\pi)=\sin x$ and $\cos(\theta+2\pi)=\cos x$.

Adding $2\pi$ to an angle $\theta$ merely wraps around the unit circle once

and ends up at the same point.

In particular, $\sin\left(\dfrac\pi2\right)=\sin\left(\dfrac\pi2+2\pi\right)=\sin\left(\dfrac{5\pi}2\right).$

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: @OGK What don’t you understand? You need to be more specific so we know what you don’t get.

Comment: @OGK:  I edited my answer to add some more explanation

Answer (score 1):

> So wouldn't extracting the five and then multiplying it by 1 give you five?

I think this is your main confusion. You think that the trig functions are linear; that is, you think you should have $$\sin(5π/2)=5\sin(π/2)=5×1=5.$$ But you should know that this is nonsense since the value of a sine can never exceed $1$ in magnitude.

In any case, we reduce this by noting that $5π/2=(4π+π)/2=2π+π/2.$ Also, we know that $\sin (x+2π)=\sin x.$ It follows that $$\sin(5π/2)=\sin(π/2+2π)=\sin(π/2)=1,$$ which makes more sense and is indeed the correct value.